# How to smooth the edge of a zig-zag line?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

Currently I draw a zig-zap line by `CGContextMoveToPoint`, `CGContextAddLineToPoint`, and `CGContextStrokePath`, following `touchesMoved` events. How can I smooth the edges of the line? Such that when the user draw a circle-like shape, the circle can be more *round'ed*. The GLPaint example use OpenGL, is that the only way to do it?

Comment: Is this possible in Apple GLPaint(OpenGL)? Did you found any solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set the line join to round, to make the edges less visible:

```
CGContextSetLineJoin(ctx, kCGLineJoinRound);
```

Other than that you option would be to use some kind of spline interpolation.

Comment: Is this possible in Apple GLPaint(OpenGL)? Please help me on this.

Comment: @Madhavan Please post this as an individual question.